# Delphi Проект ошибка использования dylib

Tags: delphi, macos, delphi-10-berlin

Использую Delphi 10.1 Berlin. Сделал приложение, которое запускаю на маке с использованием библиотеки (сам создал из кода на Си).

При запуске приложения сначала выскакивала ошибка, что не видит файла libhidlib.dylib (моя либа).
Я добавил ее в rpath, и библиотека начала подгружаться.

Теперь, когда я открыл приложение и пытаюсь вызвать функцию с этой библиотеки, получаю следующее:

```
Process:               Project2 [8538]
Path:                  /Users/USER/*/Project2.app/Contents/MacOS/Project2
Identifier:            Project2
Version:               1.0.0 (1.0.0)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Project2 [8538]
User ID:               506

Date/Time:             2018-01-23 14:03:14.976 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G29)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        4E81F6AB-1EEF-F9C1-160C-A01D8944D786

Sleep/Wake UUID:       DB3C055B-BE55-40B8-88A5-6D5530E284AB . 

Time Awake Since Boot: 140000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       14000 seconds



System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x4] Symbol missing

Dyld Error Message:
Symbol not found: _DeleteAll
Referenced from: /Users/USER/*/Project2.app/Contents/MacOS/Project2
Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libhidlib.dylib
```